# Faces flow not working with @Named

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

I'm just playing around with the `simple-flow` example from the Java EE7 tutorial. It has the following bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class FlowScope {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and the following scope directory structure:

```
simple-flow
     simple-flow.xhtml
     simple-flow-flow.xhtml ;; this file is empty
     simple-flow-return.xhml
```

It works as long as the request scoped bean uses the `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` annotation. But it stops working if I use `@Named`. Since the `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` annotation may be removed in the future I would like to know how to make it work without using the `ManagedBean` annotation.

BTW: I'm using JBoss Wildfly as the container.

Regards
  Roger

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@Named`, your bean will be managed by CDI. For this to work you need a CDI implementation in your project. If you run your application on a Java EE 6 (or 7 if available) container like TomEE, Glassfish or JBoss CDI is available by default. If you only use a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty, you have to add a CDI implementation like Apache OpenWebBeans or Weld yourself (or consider using TomEE for example).

To get a CDI request scoped bean you would have to annotate your class like this:

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    ...
}
```

JSF 2.2 also provides flow scoped beans with CDI. A flow scoped bean bound to your flow `simple-flow` wouldlook like this:

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped(value="simple-flow")
public class MyBean {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That gives me a  'WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped' exception.

Comment: It seems that if I use @Named I have to define the flow in the simple.flow.flow.xml file.